# Stop particle effect libgdx

Tags: opengl, libgdx, particles, particle-system

I have a game that involves lots of collisions and explosions.

Basically, enemy-projectiles are launched from the bottom-right corner of the screen towards the left side. The player can intercept them using his weapon.

I want whenever a "bullet" and a projectile collide, the code will draw pre-made particles at the impact position.
My problem is that in real-time, in collision, the particles are drawn nicely but they never stop. The particles continue to be drawn even after the collision.

Now, I use callback mechanism to inform the renderer a collision took place somewhere, and I pass him the coordinates of the collision(x,y)

Here is my renderer code. I cut some parts from the code, leaving only the relevant ones:

```
    package com.david.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.david.helpers.AssetsLoader;
import com.david.helpers.CollisionAndTouchCallbacks;

public class GameRenderer implements CollisionAndTouchCallbacks.DrawThings{

    /* The GameRenderer class. Responsible for all the rendering work and graphics */

    public static final float FLOOR_HEIGHT = 100.0f; // Public variable - The floor height
    private static final float Pixels_To_Meters = 32.0f; // PTM Ration
    public static float screenWidth; // Screen width
    public static float screenHeight; // Screen height
    public OrthographicCamera camera; // The orthographic camera
    private GameWorld world; // The game world object, for rendering
    private boolean drawTrajectory;
    private boolean drawParticle;
    private boolean isDrawnParticle;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer; // Debug renderer, to see the positions and sizes of the bodies/fixtures
    private SpriteBatch batch; // A sprite batch
    private Array<Body> tempBodies; // An array that contains all the bodies of Box2D
    private Array<Vector2> collisionPositions;
    private float delta;

    public GameRenderer(float screenWidth, float screenHeight, GameWorld world) {
        this.world = world;
        GameRenderer.screenHeight = screenHeight;
        GameRenderer.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        tempBodies = new Array<Body>();
        collisionPositions = new Array<Vector2>();
        drawTrajectory = false;
        drawParticle = false;
        isDrawnParticle = false;
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        this.delta = delta;
        // Update the world
        world.updateWorld();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        // Get box2d World bodies
        world.getBox2DWorld().getBodies(tempBodies);
        // Draw the entire scene
        batch.begin();
        drawBodiesBox2D();
        if(drawTrajectory)
            drawTrajectory();
        if(drawParticle) {
            if(!isDrawnParticle) {
                drawParticle();
                isDrawnParticle = true;
            } else {
                if(AssetsLoader.explosion.isComplete()) {
                    drawParticle = false;
                    isDrawnParticle = false;
                }
            }
        }

        batch.end();
        // Debug Renderer for box2d world

    }
    // If user is aiming, draw the trajectory of the acorn
    public void drawTrajectory() {
        Gdx.app.log("System Out Println!!!!!!!!!", "Draw projectile");
        float t = 0.1f, x = world.getArrayAcorns().peek().getX(), y = world
                .getArrayAcorns().peek().getY();
        float width = AssetsLoader.orbit.getWidth() / 8 / Pixels_To_Meters;
        float height = AssetsLoader.orbit.getHeight() / 8 / Pixels_To_Meters;
        float timeSeparation = 0.08f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            x = world.getAcornEquation().getX(t);
            y = world.getAcornEquation().getY(t);
            batch.draw(AssetsLoader.orbit, x, y, width, height);
            t += timeSeparation;
        }
    }
    private void drawBodiesBox2D() {
        for (Body body : tempBodies) {
            if (body.getUserData() != null
                    && body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite) {
                Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
                if (!sprite.getTexture().equals(AssetsLoader.ground)) {
                    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x - sprite.getWidth()
                            / 2, body.getPosition().y - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
                } else {
                    sprite.setSize(screenWidth, FLOOR_HEIGHT / Pixels_To_Meters);
                }
                sprite.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()));
                batch.draw(AssetsLoader.catapult_base1, 450 / Pixels_To_Meters,
                        (FLOOR_HEIGHT - 10) / Pixels_To_Meters,
                        AssetsLoader.catapult_base1.getWidth()
                                / Pixels_To_Meters,
                        AssetsLoader.catapult_base1.getHeight()
                                / Pixels_To_Meters);
                sprite.draw(batch);
            }
        }
    }
    public void dispose() {
        AssetsLoader.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        debugRenderer.dispose();
    }
    // Update method for the orthographic camera
    public void updateCamera(int width, int height) {
        camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
        screenWidth = (float) width;
        screenHeight = (float) height;
        camera.update();
        // Already Meters
    }

    public OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
        return this.camera;
    }

    private void drawParticle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AssetsLoader.explosion.setPosition(collisionPositions.first().x,collisionPositions.first().y);
        AssetsLoader.explosion.start();
        AssetsLoader.explosion.draw(batch,delta);
        AssetsLoader.explosion.allowCompletion();

    }

    @Override
    public void signalToTrajectory(boolean flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        drawTrajectory = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public void signalToParticle(boolean flag, Array<Vector2> positions) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(flag)
            collisionPositions = positions;
        drawParticle = flag;
    }

}
```

How can I draw the particle effect once and that's it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use/optimise my particle class, look [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887570/libgdx-special-effects-in-3d/27214702#27214702)

To draw the particle effect once and that's it : ( it's in myparticle free method ) :

```
    ParticleEffect effect = new ParticleEffect();
    Emitter emitter = effect.getControllers().first().emitter;
    if (emitter instanceof RegularEmitter){
        RegularEmitter reg = (RegularEmitter) emitter;
        reg.setEmissionMode(RegularEmitter.EmissionMode.EnabledUntilCycleEnd);
        //reg.durationValue.setLow(10f);
        reg.dispose();
    }
    emitter.dispose();
```